# Is there a name for graphs that appear as Hasse diagrams of finite lattices?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, lattice-orders

[Hasse diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)
are mathematical diagrams used to represent finite partially ordered sets,
and may be seen as a kind of graph.

Apparently, there are some relations between particular kinds of lattices and graphs:

1. A finite lattice is a
   [modular lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice)
   if and only if its Hasse diagram is a
   [modular graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_graph).
2. The Hasse diagram of a finite
   [distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice)
   is a [median graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_graph).

What about general finite lattices?
Is there a name for graphs that appear as Hasse diagrams of finite lattices?
Do these graphs have a special property that distinguish them from other graphs,
just like modular and median graphs do?